# Request to rename tag [zeit-now] to [vercel]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I would like to rename the existing tag [zeit-now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zeit-now) to [vercel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vercel).

Additionally, I would like [zeit-now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zeit-now) to be an alias for [vercel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vercel) for users who have not seen the announcement yet and are unaware of the new name.

See the announcement here: https://vercel.com/blog/zeit-is-now-vercel

Comment: I'm willing to action this, but I have a minor concern. Previously, it looks like "ZEIT" was the name of the company and "Now" was the name of the product. What about the new tag? If "Vercel" is the name of the company, **what is the name of the product?** We generally prefer not to have tags named after companies.

Comment: The name of the company and the product are both Vercel. The announcement links to a FAQ explaining `What is "Now" renamed to?`: https://www.notion.so/zeithq/FAQ-c726facaf7cc41c095ba49aeea90219e

Comment: Okay; thanks. I was not able to find that in my initial search. That is a bit confusing, but it is what it is.